# Get entire chain of IDs in self-referencing table given any ID in hierachy

Tags: recursion, parent-child, hierarchy, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have a table that contains the following data:

```
+----+----------+
| ID | ParentID |
+----+----------+
| 27 |    0     |
| 38 |    27    | 
| 45 |    38    |
| 86 |    0     |
| 92 |    45    |
| 48 |    86    |
| 62 |    92    |
| 50 |    62    |
-----------------
```

I would like to be able to pass ***any*** ID to a stored procedure and get the ***entire*** chain of IDs (parents and children) of that given ID.

ie. if I pass ID = 45, I should get:

```
27
38
45
92
62
50
```

Similarly, if I pass ID = 86, I should get:

```
86
48
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two recursive CTE's. The first finds the root node and the second builds the chain.

```
declare @T table(ID int, ParentID int)

insert into @T values (27,  0), (38, 27), (45, 38), (86,  0),
                      (92, 45), (48, 86), (62, 92), (50, 62)    

declare @ID int = 45

;with cte1 as
(
  select T.ID, T.ParentID, 1 as lvl
  from @T as T
  where T.ID = @ID
  union all
  select T.ID, T.ParentID, C.lvl+1
  from @T as T
    inner join cte1 as C
      on T.ID = C.ParentID
),
cte2 as
(
  select T.ID, T.ParentID
  from @T as T
  where T.ID = (select top 1 ID
                from cte1
                order by lvl desc)
  union all
  select T.ID, T.ParentID
  from @T as T
    inner join cte2 as C
      on T.ParentID = C.ID
)
select ID
from cte2
```

**Version 2**

A bit shorter and query plan suggests more effective but you never know without testing on real data.

```
;with cte as
(
  select T.ID, T.ParentID, ','+cast(@ID as varchar(max)) as IDs
  from @T as T
  where T.ID = @ID
  union all
  select T.ID, T.ParentID, C.IDs+','+cast(T.ID as varchar(10))
  from @T as T
    inner join cte as C
      on (T.ID = C.ParentID or
          T.ParentID = C.ID) and
          C.IDs+',' not like '%,'+cast(T.ID as varchar(10))+',%'
)
select ID
from cte
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Mikael. Your first solution returned the desired results.